# how to insert a matrix within another matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

We have a data set X n*m matrix and I want to create a matrix like this W=[0 X;X' 0]
how should I do that in Matlab?

```
   A=[1 2;3 4];
   B=[0 A;A' 0];
```

what's wrong with that code?

Comment: A is 2x2 and the 0 only 1x1 so the dimensions dont add up. `B=[[0;0] A;A' [0;0]];` would create a 4x3 if that was your goal. `B=[zeros(2) A; A' zeros(2)]` if you wanted a 4x4 but in every case you have to add enough 0s to match the dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution using [kron](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html):

```
A = [1 2; 3 4]

result = kron([0 1;0 0], A) + kron([0 0;1 0], A');

result =

   0   0   1   2
   0   0   3   4
   1   3   0   0
   2   4   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `zeros` to make sure the dimensions agree

```
A = [1 2; 3 4];
z = zeros( size( A ) );
B = [ z, A; A', z ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the size of `0` is not the as `A` and `A'` in row and column.
You can create a matrix with the size of what you want:

```
B = zeros(2*size(A));
```

and replace the value where you want:

```
B(1:2, 3:4) = A;
B(3:4, 1:2) = A.';
```